# Fastest File Explorer for loading 10k thumbnails?

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, filemanager

I have folders with 10k jpgs of size 84x84 pixels. Trying to scroll through them to find differences. What is the best file explorer to load images fast?

I used nautilus but that is single core, and so is painfully slow. Switched to nemo, but that maxes out it seems at 2 cores with one core taking 120% while the other core only doing 30%.

Specs is 12 cores, 32 gb ram (nvidia 1660)
Ubuntu 20.04